# Выборка записей, одновременно имеющих несколько значений

Tags: select, mysql

Есть таблица

```
+----------------+------------------------+
| item_option_id | select_option_value_id |
+----------------+------------------------+
|            164 |                     10 |
|            168 |                     16 |
|            168 |                     18 |
+----------------+------------------------+
```

Необходимо выбрать `item_option_id`, для которого `select_option_value_id` одновременно равен и 16, и 18...

Использовать в запросе `OR`, т.е.

```
select_option_value_id = 16 OR select_option_value_id = 18
```

или

```
select_option_value_id IN (16, 18)
```

не вариант, так как если `select_option_value_id` будет равен только 16, то `item_option_id` всё равно выберется.

Использовать `AND` не получается, так как при поиске по условию

```
select_option_value_id = 16 AND select_option_value_id = 18
```

MySQL найдя строку с `select_option_value_id = 16` все остальные отбрасывает и условие проваливается, так как нет строки где `select_option_value_id = 18`.

Текущий запрос такой:

```
SELECT item_option_id
FROM items_select_options_values
WHERE select_option_value_id IN (16,18)
GROUP BY item_option_id;
```

**Решение:**

```
SELECT item_option_id
FROM items_select_options_values
WHERE select_option_value_id IN (16,18)
GROUP BY item_option_id
HAVING COUNT(item_option_id) = {{количество значений, в данном случае 2}};
```

Comment: а чем вам ваш собственный вариант не нравится?

Comment: А тем что он вернёт 168 даже в случае если строки со значениями 168/16 не будет

Comment: @braska

> Необходимо выбрать item_option_id для которого select_option_value_id одновременно равен и 16 и 18... 

Он не может быть **одновременно** равен 16 и 18. Вы можете выбрать все записи, в которых он равен [одному], [другому] или [одному или другому].

> так как при поиске по условию select_option_value_id = 16 AND select_option_value_id = 18, MySQL найдя строку с select_option_value_id = 16 все остальные отбрасывает и условие проваливается так как нет строки где select_option_value_id = 18.

Это эм неверно. Боюсь, вы неправильно понимаете логику вопроса.

Comment: @braska ваше решение выдаст тру для строк 168/16 168/16.

Comment: @ua6xh такого сочетания строк никогда не будет. Так как, во-первых уникальный индекс по двум столбцам, а во-вторых это протеворечит логике и запрещено кодом.

Comment: @Etki я понимаю что одно поле не может одновременно содержать два значения. Тут речь о двух разных значениях (16,18) в разных строках, сопоставленных с одним айдишником (item_option_id). У меня просто была надежда, что в mysql есть что-то типо IN и AND в одном флаконе.

Comment: @braska, когда мускуль проходит по таблице, он проверяет каждую запись отдельно на соответствие заданным в запросе условиям. В этот момент других записей не существует (их наличие можн опроверить через джойн, подзапрос или exists-подзапрос). Таким образом, в where должно оказаться такое условие, которое однозначно будет определять необходимость строки прямо в этот конкретный момент.

Comment: У меня подобная проблема была. [Вот][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/334899/mysql-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем у меня получилось как-то так (вроде работает):

```
SELECT
    TT.item_option_id
FROM
    TestTable TT
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        item_option_id
        ,COUNT(*) Cnt
    FROM
        TestTable
    GROUP BY
        item_option_id
) X ON X.item_option_id= TT.item_option_id
WHERE
    select_option_value_id IN (16, 18)
GROUP BY
    TT.item_option_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = MAX(X.Cnt)
```

Comment: Сложно, нагруженно, но можно)