# Запрос mysql AND

Tags: mysql

Есть фильтр, в котором пользователь выбрал необходимое.
И получен такой массив:

```
[
‘property_id’=>8,
‘value’=>2
]
[
‘property_id’=>99,
‘value’=>10
]
```

И нам необходимо, чтобы и первая пара значений совпала, и вторая. Т.е. чтобы не было  или вторая, или первая, а чтобы обе пары были равны значениям  и обе такие строки  имелись в таблице.

Примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM tables WHERE (property_id=8 AND value=2) AND (property_id=99 AND value=10)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выборка записей одновременно имеющий несколько значений](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/354353/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1):

[Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/354353/mysql-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Похоже на то, что спрашивающий сам нашел ответ и написал его в конце вопроса.